# Pygame: stopping character movement when a key is pressed in the opposite direction

Tags: python, pygame

Basically, my game involves moving a character around a screen with collectable rects and obstacle rects. That's not the issue I'm having. My problem arises in "easy" mode, where I want the character to stop moving when the key opposite the direction they are moving in is pressed. For example, if the character is moving left and the right arrow is pressed, I want them to stop moving. I think the issue is that the program thinks the right press continues past when it stops the character from moving and so detects it as just trying to move right. If you tap the key quickly enough it doesn't happen. It's just a project I'm working on for myself so it's just annoying really. Also please excuse how messy the code is, I've tried many different approaches so if anything looks like it's not going anywhere it's because it isn't.

```py
import os, random, pygame, time

difficulty = input("Enter difficulty level. \nEASY\nNORMAL\n>>> ")
while difficulty.lower() not in ("easy", "normal"):
    difficulty = input("Enter difficulty level. \nEASY\nNORMAL\n>>> ")
if "easy" in difficulty:
    easy = True
else:
    easy = False


pygame.init()

# Defining variables
SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H = 600, 600
MAP_W, MAP_H = 2000, 2000
BACKGROUND = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(
    os.path.join("Assets", "image.png")), (MAP_W, MAP_H)) # Change this to work with whatever images you have

cameraOffset = [MAP_W//2-SCREEN_W//2, MAP_H//2-SCREEN_H//2]
move_dir = ""

objects = []
apples = []
deadly_objects = []
wallobjects = []
start_of_game = True

wall_text, wall_pop_text = None, None

SPEED = 10
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H))
FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
delay = 8
    
PLAYER_W, PLAYER_H = 40, 40



player = pygame.Rect(MAP_W//2-PLAYER_W, MAP_H//2-PLAYER_H, PLAYER_W, PLAYER_H)
for i in range(5):
    apple = pygame.Rect(i*200, i*200, 30, 30)
    apples.append(apple)

right_wall, left_wall = pygame.Rect(MAP_W, 0, 200, MAP_H+30), pygame.Rect(20, 0, 20, MAP_H+30)
up_wall = pygame.Rect(0,20,MAP_W,20)
down_wall = pygame.Rect(0, MAP_H, MAP_W, 20)
for i in range(10):
    if random.randint(0,1) == 1:
        mid_wall = pygame.Rect(random.randint(100, MAP_W-100), random.randint(100, MAP_H-100), 20, 80)
    else:
        mid_wall = pygame.Rect(random.randint(100, MAP_W-100), random.randint(100, MAP_H-100), 80, 20)
    for i in apples:
        while pygame.Rect.colliderect(mid_wall, i):
            if random.randint(0,1) == 1:
                mid_wall = pygame.Rect(random.randint(100, MAP_W-100), random.randint(100, MAP_H-100), 20, 80)
            else:
                 mid_wall = pygame.Rect(random.randint(100, MAP_W-100), random.randint(100, MAP_H-100), 80, 20)
    objects.append(mid_wall)
wallobjects.append(right_wall)
wallobjects.append(left_wall)
wallobjects.append(up_wall)
wallobjects.append(down_wall)
    
text_font = pygame.font.SysFont("times new roman", 40)
death_font = pygame.font.SysFont("times new roman",60)
press_font = pygame.font.SysFont("times new roman",30, False, True)
notification = pygame.font.SysFont("times new roman", 15, True, True)
notification_big = pygame.font.SysFont("times new roman", 20, True, True)

score = 0

def collision(x, y): # Looking for a collision with an object
    global player, objects, wallobjects
    new_player = pygame.Rect(x,y, PLAYER_W, PLAYER_H)
    for i in objects:
        if pygame.Rect.colliderect(i, new_player):
            return True
    for i in wallobjects:
        if pygame.Rect.colliderect(i, new_player):
            return True
    return False

def display_death_screen():
    global move_dir, score
    score = 0
    move_dir = ""
    
    player.x, player.y = MAP_W//2, MAP_H//2
    text = death_font.render("YOU DIED", 1, (0,0,255))
    WIN.blit(text, (SCREEN_W//2-SCREEN_W//3, SCREEN_H//2-50))
    press_enter = press_font.render("Press enter to respawn...", 0, (255,0,50))
    WIN.blit(press_enter, (SCREEN_W//2-140, SCREEN_H//2+10))

    if wall_pop_text != None and pygame.time.get_ticks() < wall_end_pop:
        WIN.blit(wall_pop_text, (SCREEN_W-140, 15))
    
    pygame.display.update()
    
def handle_movement(pressed, player): # Problem is in this function I think
    global cameraOffset, playerScreenPos, move_dir, start_of_game
    # The collision checking could probably be done better but it works like this (actually probably the case with most of this code lol)

    movement_window = pygame.time.get_ticks() + # Even if you put a ridiculous number here it makes no difference
    
    if easy == False:
        if (pressed[pygame.K_a] or pressed[pygame.K_LEFT] or move_dir == "left") and player.x - (SPEED + player.width//2) > 0 and move_dir != "right": # left
            move_dir = "left"
            player.x -= SPEED

        if (pressed[pygame.K_d] or pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT] or move_dir == "right") and player.x + (SPEED + player.width//2) < MAP_W and move_dir != "left": # right
            move_dir = "right"
            player.x += SPEED

        if (pressed[pygame.K_w]or pressed[pygame.K_UP] or move_dir == "up") and player.y - (SPEED + player.width//2) > 0 and move_dir != "down": # up
            move_dir = "up"
            player.y -= SPEED
    
        if (pressed[pygame.K_s] or pressed[pygame.K_DOWN] or move_dir == "down") and player.y + (SPEED + player.height//2) < MAP_H and move_dir != "up": # down
            move_dir = "down"
            player.y += SPEED

        
    else:
        if move_dir == "":
            if pygame.time.get_ticks() < movement_window:
                start_of_game = False
                move_dir = "."
        
        if (pressed[pygame.K_a] or pressed[pygame.K_LEFT] or move_dir == "left") and player.x - (SPEED + player.width//2) > 0 and move_dir != "": # left
            if move_dir == "right":
                move_dir = ""
            if move_dir != "" and not start_of_game:
                move_dir = "left"
                player.x -= SPEED

        if (pressed[pygame.K_d] or pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT] or move_dir == "right") and player.x + (SPEED + player.width//2) < MAP_W and move_dir != "": # right
            if move_dir == "left":
                move_dir = ""
            if move_dir != "" and not start_of_game:
                move_dir = "right"
                player.x += SPEED

        if (pressed[pygame.K_w]or pressed[pygame.K_UP] or move_dir == "up") and player.y - (SPEED + player.width//2) > 0 and move_dir != "": # up
            if move_dir == "down":
                move_dir = ""
            if move_dir != ""and not start_of_game:
                move_dir = "up"
                player.y -= SPEED
    
        if (pressed[pygame.K_s] or pressed[pygame.K_DOWN] or move_dir == "down") and player.y + (SPEED + player.height//2) < MAP_H and move_dir != "": # down
            if move_dir == "up":
                move_dir = ""
            if move_dir != "" and not start_of_game:
                move_dir = "down"
                player.y += SPEED

    cameraOffset[0] += (player.x - cameraOffset[0] - (SCREEN_W * 0.5)) / delay
    cameraOffset[1] += (player.y - cameraOffset[1] - (SCREEN_H * 0.5)) / delay

    cameraOffset[0] = max(0, min(cameraOffset[0], MAP_W - SCREEN_W))
    cameraOffset[1] = max(0, min(cameraOffset[1], MAP_H - SCREEN_H))



def add_wall():
    global mid_wall, objects, wall_text, wall_end

    wall_text = notification.render("Wall added", 1, (255,0,0))
    wall_end = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 3000
        
    if random.randint(0,1) == 1:
        mid_wall = pygame.Rect(random.randint(100, MAP_W-100), random.randint(100, MAP_H-100), 20, 80)
    else:
        mid_wall = pygame.Rect(random.randint(100, MAP_W-100), random.randint(100, MAP_H-100), 80, 20)
    for i in apples:
        while pygame.Rect.colliderect(mid_wall, i) or pygame.Rect.colliderect(mid_wall, pygame.Rect(player.x-100, player.y-100, player.width+100, player.height+100)):
            if random.randint(0,1) == 1:
                mid_wall = pygame.Rect(random.randint(100, MAP_W-100), random.randint(100, MAP_H-100), 20, 80)
            else:
                mid_wall = pygame.Rect(random.randint(100, MAP_W-100), random.randint(100, MAP_H-100), 80, 20)
    
    objects.append(mid_wall)

def remove_wall():
    global wall_pop_text, wall_end_pop
    if len(objects) > 0:
        wall_remove = random.choice(objects)
    
        wall_pop_text = notification.render("Wall removed", 1, (255,0,0))
        wall_end_pop = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 3000

        objects.remove(wall_remove)

def handle_apple():
    global score
    for i in apples:
        x, y = i.x-cameraOffset[0], i.y-cameraOffset[1]
        pygame.draw.circle(WIN, (255,0,0), (x, y), i.width//2)
        if pygame.Rect.colliderect(player, i):
            apples.remove(i)
            score += 1
            if score % 5 == 0 and score != 0:
                add_wall()
            xx, yy = random.randint(40,MAP_H-40), random.randint(40,MAP_H-40)
            for i in objects:
                while pygame.Rect.colliderect(pygame.Rect(xx, yy, 30, 30), i):
                    xx, yy = random.randint(40,MAP_H-40), random.randint(40,MAP_H-40)
            apple = pygame.Rect(xx, yy, 30, 30)
            apples.append(apple)
            
            

def draw_screen(player): # Drawing to the screen
    global wall_text, wall_end
 
    WIN.blit(BACKGROUND, (0 - cameraOffset[0], 0 - cameraOffset[1]))

    score_disp = text_font.render("Score: "+str(score), 0, (255,255,255))
    wall_amount = notification_big.render("Walls: "+str(len(objects)), 0, (255,255,255))
    press_space_text = notification_big.render("Movement Paused", 0, (255,255,255))
        
    handle_apple()
    playerPos = ((player.x - PLAYER_W//2) - cameraOffset[0], (player.y-PLAYER_H//2) - cameraOffset[1])
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, (100, 10, 255), (*playerPos, player.width, player.height))
                
    for i in objects:
        numberx = i.width // 20
        numbery = i.height // 20
        try:
            pygame.draw.rect(WIN, (0,0,0), (i.x - cameraOffset[0] - i.width// numberx, i.y - cameraOffset[1] - i.height//numbery, i.width, i.height))
        except:
            numberx = i.width 
            numbery = i.height
    
    for i in wallobjects:
        numberx = i.width // 20
        numbery = i.height // 20
        try:
            pygame.draw.rect(WIN, (0,0,0), (i.x - cameraOffset[0] - i.width// numberx, i.y - cameraOffset[1] - i.height//numbery, i.width, i.height))
        except:
            numberx = i.width 
            numbery = i.height
            
    if wall_text != None and pygame.time.get_ticks() < wall_end:
        WIN.blit(wall_text, (SCREEN_W-120, 15))

    if wall_pop_text != None and pygame.time.get_ticks() < wall_end_pop:
        WIN.blit(wall_pop_text, (SCREEN_W-140, 15))

    if easy and move_dir == "":
        WIN.blit(press_space_text, (SCREEN_W//2-200, SCREEN_H//2+player.height+5))
    
    WIN.blit(score_disp, (10, 10))
    WIN.blit(wall_amount, (10, SCREEN_H-30))
                 
    pygame.display.update()



def main():
    global cameraOffset, move_dir
    running, dead = True, False
    while running:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        if collision(player.x, player.y):
            remove_wall()
            dead = True
        if dead:
            display_death_screen()
        if not dead:
            draw_screen(player)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    running = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN and dead:
                    dead = False
        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        handle_movement(keys_pressed, player)
        
        

    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify the logic:

```py
left  = pressed[pygame.K_a] or pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]
right = pressed[pygame.K_d] or pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]
up    = pressed[pygame.K_w] or pressed[pygame.K_UP]
down  = pressed[pygame.K_s] or pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]
    
player.x += (right - left) * SPEED
player.y += (down - up) * SPEED
```